# What's the difference between a node and an engine in SymmetricDS?

Tags: symmetricds

https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/user-guide.html says

```
Multiple nodes can be hosted in a single SymmetricDS instance.
SymmetricDS will start a node for each properties file it finds
in the engines directory.
```

Each .properties file specifies an `engine.name` and an `external.id`. They are described as follows

- `engine.name`: This is the engine name.  This should be set if you have more than one engine running in the same JVM
- `external.id`: The external id is usually used as all or part of the node id.

Based on this I would guess there is a 1-1 mapping between nodes and engines. Is this correct? Are nodes and engines kind of the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The mapping is 1-1